# Prototypes etc in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

Should you you use classes, prototypes etc in Angular JS? I learned Angular JS before I learned Javascript (bad idea). Now I've started to read some about OOP in javascript. I'm very confused at the moment.

I have an example. It's a service. It has some data from server and some input from user. It runs som logic and populate the object which is then viewed for the user.

**Option 1.** Just an object. I've removed most of the code so it's more a pseudo code. This is the way you see in most examples and tutorials.

```
  angular.module('calculationServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('CalculationFactory', function(UnitsFactory){

    var calculations =  {
      mainCalculation: function(sizes, pipe, temperature){
        if(sizes === null || temperature === null){
          return;
        }
        var rawness = pipe.rawness;
        var mediaDensity = temperature.density;
        var results = [],
          nrOfSizes = sizes.length;
        for(var i = 0;i<nrOfSizes;i++){
          var flow = this.input.flow.valueInSIunit;
          var velocitySiUnit = this.velocityFN(sizes[i].innerdiameter/1000,flow);
          var pressureDropInSiUnit = this.pressureDropFN(velocitySiUnit,mediaDensity, frictionFactor, sizes[i].innerdiameter/1000);
          results.push({
            size:sizes[i].nominalsize
            innerDiameter:sizes[i].innerdiameter,
            velocity:{
              siUnit:velocitySiUnit,
              userUnit:velocityUserUnit
            }
          });
        }
        return results;
      },
      powerFN: function(flow, cp, density, deltaT){
        var power = flow * cp * deltaT * density;
        return power;
      },
      velocityFN: function(innerDiameter, flow){
        var area = Math.PI * Math.pow((innerDiameter) * 0.5 ,2);
        return flow / area;
      },
      input: { //Input is hooked up to my $scope
        flow:{
          valueInSIunit: 0.00075,
          value:0.75,
          unit: 'l/s'
        }
      },
    };
    return calculations;

  })
})
```

**Option 2** Or. should I use classes, instantiating, prototypes etc. Something like this:

```
  factory('CalculationFactory', function(UnitsFactory){

    function PipeCalculations(params){
      this.flow = params.flow;
      this.pipe = params.pipe;
      this.sizes = params.sizes;
    }

    PipeCalculations.prototype.velocityFN = function(flow, innerDiameter){
      var area = Math.PI * Math.pow((innerDiameter) * 0.5 ,2);
      return flow / area;
    }

    PipeCalculations.prototype.createPipeCalculationObjects = function(sizes){
      var results = [];
      var nrOfSizes = sizes.length;
      var velocitySiUnit = this.velocityFN(sizes[i].innerdiameter/1000,flow);
      for(var i = 0;i<nrOfSizes;i++){
        results.push({
          size:sizes[i].nominalsize,
          velocity:{
            siUnit:velocitySiUnit
          }
        });
      }
      return results;
    };

    var pipeCalculations = new PipeCalculations({
      flow: { //Should this be hooked up directly to my scope?
        valueInSiUnit: 55,
        valueInUserUnit: 0.75
      },
      pipe: 0, //Data feed from controller
      sizes: 0
    });

    pipeCalculations.velocity = pipeCalculations.velocityFN(pipeCalculations.flow.valueInSiUnit, 25);
    pipeCalculations.output = pipeCalculations.createPipeCalculationObjects(pipeCalculations.sizes);

    return pipeCalculations;
})
```

Is there a clear right and wrong here? I did option one first. It was very easy and everything worked smoothly. But it didn't feel quite "OOP". However, option 2 is much harder for me because it's difficult to find decent examples. Also, with option one I can simply attach my scope to my model and everything is updated automatically. But how do i do it correctly with option 2? Should i instantiate from my controller?